# DataGridView rows are duplicated

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, vba

I Connected My DB(Created using Acces 2017 ) To Visual Basic Using Oledb4.0
The problem i'm facing is that the datagridview show duplicated rows 
For Example on my DB I have 2 rows it Will show four rows 
What is the problem ?

```
 cnx = New OleDbConnection
    dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source =C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\PFA\FLYY.mdb"
    cnx.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    cnx.Open()
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Login.* from Login"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql)
    dta = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    cmd.Connection() = cnx
    dta.Fill(dts, "Login")
    dtt = dts.Tables("Login")
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dtt.Load(dr)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtt
    dta.Fill(ds, "Login")
    dsview = ds.Tables("Login").DefaultView
    bs.DataSource = dsview
```

Comment: Please Don't randomly Capitalize words In Your question.

Comment: For Example on my DB I have 2 rows it Will show two rows What is the problem ? ?????

Comment: sorry i ment it will show four rows

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `DataTable.Load` if you already `.Fill` it.

So you can remove:

```
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
dtt.Load(dr)
```